# Does EasyMock.anyObject() match a null parameter?

Tags: java, easymock

My SUT may call a method on my mock with any object as paramter, including `null`.

So, does `EasyMock.anyObject()` match a `null` parameter? or can I use something else instead of `anyObject()` which will also match `null` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since EasyMock also offers matchers for `notNull()` and `null()`, I assume the answer is yes - otherwise `anyObject()` and `notNull()` would be redundant (if `anyObject()` did not match null).

A simple test confirms this.

Answer (score 3):

`eq((String) null)` will work for a String param which is `null`.